# Python 3, Turning csv file into a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, csv, io

File is something like:

```
6, 'bird', 'flies', False
```

and it needs to be ordered like:

```
{'bird': (6,'flies', False)}
```

This is what I have so far but not formatting right.

```
{"'bird'": '1'}
```

My current code:

```
def read_info_file(filename):

    d = {}
    count = 0

    file = open(filename, "r")
    lines = file.readlines()

    for line in lines:
        split = tuple(line.split(","))

        if count > 0:
            d[split[1]] = split[0]
        count += 1

    return d
```

I can also not import any modules in this question.

Comment: Also, **show** us what you mean by "not formatting right".

Comment: Also, you would probably find it easier to use the built-in [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

Answer (score 2):

Hand parsing `csv` files with Python is often more work than it is worth.  Here is one simple way to parse individual lines, use a generator, while still using the `csv` module:

**Code:**

```
import csv

def parse_my_csv(csv_file):
    for line in csv_file.readlines():
        # replacing comma/space with comma
        yield line.replace(", ", ",")

with open('myfile.csv', 'rU') as csvfile:
    csv_read = csv.reader(parse_my_csv(csvfile), quotechar="'")
    for row in csv_read:
        d = {row[1]: (int(row[0]), row[2], bool(row[3]))}
        print(d)
```

**Results:**

```
{'bird': (6, 'flies', True)}
```

Answer (score 1):

**The below does format the csv according to your format requirement.**

**Code:**

import csv

from pprint import pprint

def filter(str):

```
str = str.strip().strip("'")
return str
```

def read_info_file(filepath):

```
try:

    res = {}

    csvfile = open(filepath,'r')
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)

    for row in csv_reader:
        res[filter(row[1])] = (int(row[0]),filter(row[2]),bool(row[3]))

except Exception as e:
    print("Exception occurred: " + str(e))
finally:
    csvfile.close()
return res
```

res = read_info_file('file.csv')
pprint(res)

**Output:**

{'animal': (7, 'flies', True),
 'bird': (6, 'flies', True),
 'insect': (8, 'flies', True)}

Comment: You undid my editing and broke the format of your answer.

Comment: I sadly can't import anything for this question

Answer (score 0):

To do this without any imported modules, you can use comprehensions like:

**Code:**

```
def read_info_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rU') as f:
        return {row[1]: (int(row[0]), row[2], bool(row[3]))
                for row in [
                    [c.strip().strip("'") for c in line.split(',')]
                    for line in f.readlines()
                ]}
```

**Test:**

```
print(read_info_file('myfile.csv'))
```

**Result:**

```
{'bird': (6, 'flies', True)}
```